# PHP - Replace apostrophe

Tags: php, string, url, replace, apostrophe

I am currently developing a website with a list of names. Some of the names include apostrophes `'` and I want to link them to a website using their name.

I want to link to the a url like:
example.com/ (their name)

And by doing that, I first replace " " with "+". So the links looks like: example.com/john+doe

But if the name is John'Doe it turns the url into just example.com/john

And skips the lastname.

How can I fix this? I tried changing `'`, `\'` etc, to html codes, to ', and more, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my current code:

```
$name = $row['name'];
$new_name = str_replace(
    array("'", "&#39;"),
    array(" ", "+"),
    $name
);

echo "<td>" . $name . " <a href='http://www.example.com/name=" . $new_name . "' target='_blank'></a>" . "</td>";
```

What I want it to look like:

```
John Doe Johnson ----> http://www.example.com/name=John+Doe+Johnson
John'Doe Johnson ----> http://www.example.com/name=John'Doe+Johnson
```

It changes the spaces to +, but how can I fix the apostrophes? Anyone knows?

Comment: It looks like something is going on with the example.com server. The apostrophe character *is a valid character* in URLs. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conan_O'Brien

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using PHP's function `urlencode`, php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php.

```
<?php
$name = $row['name'];
//$urlname = urlencode('John\'Doe Johnson');
$urlname = urlencode($name);
echo "<td>$name<a href='http://www.example.com/name=$urlname' target='_blank'>$name</a></td>";
```

Output:

```
<td>John%27Doe+Johnson <a href='http://www.example.com/name=John%27Doe+Johnson' target='_blank'></a></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo urlencode("John'Doe Johnson");
```

return

```
John%27Doe+Johnson
```